# Meditation timer that reports mindful minutes to the Health app?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, health.app, health-kit

Is there a simple meditation timer app that actually logs time spent meditating to the Health app as mindful minutes? I need just a simple timer, no guided meditation (and certainly no subscription). Preferably an Apple Watch app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app I'm currently using is called [Meditate (Watch)](https://www.rhythmicworks.com/products/meditate-watch/). The developer emailed me and explained the situation: the only way an app can stay foremost and running on the watch is to open an Activity. That's how all the other apps work.

Meditate is different: you start a meditation, and the app runs a timer. When the meditation is complete, you get a notification on the watch, which you tap to re-open the app and save the session.

The downside of this is that you can't glance at your watch and check your progress while you meditate. The upside is that it correctly stores mindful minutes without recording to the Activity app. FTW.

The app is very simple and elegantly designed, and I find that it works great for me. I use [Streaks](https://streaksapp.com) to motivate me to keep meditating, and these two apps communicate automatically through the Health app data. Recommended!

Answer (score 2):

[Sattva - Meditation Timer & Tracker](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/sattva-meditation-timer-tracker/id930904592?mt=8)

Sattva is the world’s first advanced meditation timer and tracker with challenges, trophies and guided meditations to inspire you to meditate everyday!

Has the features you requested:

- Apple health kit integration for mindfulness (minutes)
- Apple Watch app

Comment: Thanks--it works! (I sent the developer of the other app an email, maybe they will fix the problem. I think I actually liked that one better--simple and uncluttered. Sattva has an Apple Watch app tho. Anyway, thanks again!)

Comment: Whoops: when you meditate with the Apple Watch Sattva app it doesn't record the time, only the iPhone app. Timeless works correctly from the watch and the phone.

Comment: See [below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303493/23813): Timeless doesn't actually work the way I'd like either, but Meditate (Watch) does.

Answer (score 1):

After many months of trying different apps, the one that best addresses what I need is [Timeless](https://www.timeless-meditation.us). Sattva does not log meditation time when you meditate on the watch. Timeless does, though you have to open the iPhone app after meditating to get it to log the time.

I'll just editorialize a little and say that it's crazy that, in the Mindfulness section of the Health app, Apple promotes a bunch of apps that don't record mindful minutes.

Answer (score 0):

[Meditation Timer and Log](https://appsto.re/nl/dUBxab.i)

This free app is for anyone who enjoys meditation. It's lightweight, simple to use and has bubbly feeling to lift you up. Practice meditation in the way you like it, and we will help you to personalize and keep track of your meditation activities.

In the latest update it added: "Integration with Apple Health".

Comment: This is a nice app. However it has a fatal flaw (bug?): it saves meditation sessions to the Health app as Workouts, not Mindful Minutes!

Answer (score 0):

I can really recommend Samsara, https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/samsara-timer/id592333521?mt=8. It's a meditation timer without distractions, and yet it has enough options to customise. If you use it on your iPhone, it will automatically log your meditation as Mindfulness Minutes in Apple Health.